# CosmosDB TransactionaBatch multiple containers

Tags: .net, wpf, transactions, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am developing a windows application using WPF .NET Core and I need to perform an query in my `Cosmos DB` database in which I need to remove some items from the main stock and place it on different storages, needless to say if the query which deduces the items from the `stock Container` fails the update in `storage Container` must fail too, and vice versa.

I was reading about CosmosDB `TransactionalBatch` in [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-transactionalbatch-in-the-net-sdk/) and it looks exactly what I'm looking for. However, it looks like it just works in queries in the same container, is there anyway to perform two `TransactionalBatch` operations and link them to each other, if not, is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Transactions in Cosmos DB are scoped to a logical partition, not a container. And the partition key for all items in the same transaction must share the same value.

If you find you have to do a high volume of operations across two containers you may want to take a look at your overall model and design. It's not uncommon for related data to be stored in the same container and partition key even if the entities have different schemas.

Comment: Just as apoint, we have found the transaction ability limited to just one partition completely useless. If you look at AWS DynamoDB, transactions can span multiple tables (or containers in cosmosdb) which is much more superior.